# How to resolve network error code 0x2746?

Tags: sql-server-2012

We are frequently receives ""Network error code 0x2746 occurred while establishing a connection."" In both windows event viewer and SQL error.
We tried to check from windows as well as network team end, but they arises hand that it need to be check from db end.
When application team facing slowness they are showing and send ind such error and blamed to db team.
Can anyone have idea to resolve this network issue.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason, here are two links that will help you debug the issue. I would look through your error logs for 18456 errors. Aaron Bertrand has an excellent blog on that topic.

- [Troubleshoot Connectivity/Login failures (18456 State x) with SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsakthi/2011/02/06/troubleshoot-connectivitylogin-failures-18456-state-x-with-sql-server/)
- [Troubleshooting Error 18456](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456)

Comment: Answers need to contain more than links to off-site resources. If the target of those links is unavailable for some reason (off-line, moved, or whatever), your answer loses all meaning. If all you have to offer is external links, they should be in comments to the original question instead.

Comment: No arguments here.